# Adding an angled back to a bench

Tags: design

I'm planning to build a bench for my in-laws. This is the basic plan:
(it's 150x70x40cm). The body will be made from 2.5cm by 12.5cm wood and the legs are 10x10cm.

I want to make an angled back (so that you can lean on it) - nothing crazy, around 10-15 degrees. What's the best way to add one to structure? 
[image]

Comment: "Best way" questions are usually not the ideal way to ask things since there's no one best option in almost all cases. But in this case I would argue there is one best way and that would be to make the rear legs and the back support in a single piece, just like on most chairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the back to be firmly braced by the bench base. To do so extend the back bench legs up to the height of the top of the back and connect them with a horizontal beam.  You can then set the angle by extending supports at the sides and two center supports down from the top to the seat support framing.

Comment: That'a exactly what I came up with too!